# MySQL get data from a query result

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, cordova

I am a newbie to PHP and MySQL development. I have built an app in Cordova using Visual Studio. The app works in the following way:

1. User selects a serial number from a drop down
2. After selecting a serial number, the data is showed on the chart
3. There is a toggle switch in the app, through which i am inserting the `on` or `off` state in the database based on the `serial number`

**What I want to do?**

When a user select any serial number, the switch will show the last `ON` or `Off` state based on `Command Name` of that particular `serial number`.

For this, I have generated a `msql query` and this query shows me the last `command name` of selected serial number

Below is my PHP code:

```
<?php
 require_once('config.php');

 $dsn = $_REQUEST['Device_Serial_Number'];
 $cmd_Name = $_REQUEST['Command_Name'];

 $sqlFet = "select ADC.Server_Device_Command_ID , ADC.Device_ID ,
 ADC.Server_Command_ID as Server_Command_ID, ASD.Command_Name
 from ADS_Server_Device_Command ADC
 inner join ADS_Server_Command ASD on adc.Server_Command_ID = asd.Server_Command_ID
 inner join ADS_Device dsn on adc.Device_ID = dsn.Device_ID
 where dsn.Device_Serial_Number = '$dsn'
 order by adc.Server_Device_Command_ID desc LIMIT 1";

  $result = mysqli_query($con,$sqlFet);

  mysqli_close($con);
  echo $cmd_Name;

?>
```

Below is my AJAX call in JavaScript:

```
 $.ajax({
                method: "GET",
                url: "http://localhost:MyPort/server/toggleFetch.php",

                data: { Command_Name: tData , Device_Serial_Number: selectedVal },
                success: function (data) {
                    var dt = data;
                    if (dt.Command_Name == "On") {
                        $("#cmn-toggle-7").prop('checked', true);
                    }
                    else if (dt.Command_Name == "Off") {
                        console.log('else');

                        $("#cmn-toggle-7").prop('checked', false);
                    }

                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                   alert(xhr.responseText, status, error);
                    //toastr.success('Data not fetched', '', { timeOut: 2000 })
                    //alert('Error');
                }

            });
```

But it doesn't show the required result and gives error as shown in below image:

[image]

**Updated Code:**

Bellow is my `php` updated code

```
require_once('config.php');

$dsn = $_REQUEST['Device_Serial_Number'];
//$cmd_Name = $_REQUEST['Command_Name'];

$sqlFet = "select ADC.Server_Device_Command_ID , ADC.Device_ID ,
ADC.Server_Command_ID as Server_Command_ID, ASD.Command_Name
from ADS_Server_Device_Command ADC
inner join ADS_Server_Command ASD on adc.Server_Command_ID = asd.Server_Command_ID
inner join ADS_Device dsn on adc.Device_ID = dsn.Device_ID
where dsn.Device_Serial_Number = '$dsn'
order by adc.Server_Device_Command_ID desc LIMIT 1";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sqlFet);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH);


mysqli_close($con);
echo $row["Command_Name"];
```

Bellow is the ajax

```
 $.ajax({
                method: "GET",
                url: "http://localhost:MyPort/server/toggleFetch.php",
                //dataType: "json",
                data: { Command_Name: tData , Device_Serial_Number: selectedVal },
                success: function (data) {

                    var dt = data;

                    if (dt == "On") {
                        $("#cmn-toggle-7").prop('checked', true);
                    }
                    else if (dt == "Off") {
                        console.log('else');

                        $("#cmn-toggle-7").prop('checked', false);
                    }

                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                   alert(xhr.responseText, status, error);
                    //toastr.success('Data not fetched', '', { timeOut: 2000 })
                    //alert('Error');
                }

            });
```

Now when running the code i am not getting any error but still i am not getting my required result i.e. the toggle doesn't change it's state

For more information please see the image bellow

[image]

I don't know what's the problem, any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: is the php code what's in `toggleFetch.php`?

Comment: well the thing is, there wouldn't be any dt.Command_name as its not a json object and thus nothing to really get from. If you simply put the data into a div, you'll probably just see the text of `echo $cmd_Name;` So try `echo json_encode($cmd_Name);` and see if it shows up. Otherwise you might need to `JSON.parse()` it

Comment: Ok let me try, i'll tell you

Comment: @A.Lau tried with `JSON.parse()` and without it but still getting same error

Comment: what is `echo $cmd_Name;` supposed to be echoing?

Comment: @A.Lau it should echo the last command name of the selected serial number

Comment: if you put the return into a div, what does it return?

Comment: what do your `console.log` say now?

Comment: @A.Lau nothing the console is empty

Answer (score 0):

This error means, that AJAX didnt send Command_Name via GET. You will have to check variable tData if it contains some value.

Comment: When a user select any serial number, the switch will show the last ON or Off state based on Command Name of that particular serial number.

For this, I have generated a msql query and this query shows me the last command name of selected serial number

Below is my PHP code:

Answer (score 0):

First step: dont send command_name with AJAX to PHP script (This causes Error on Line 5!!), it is not needed. Second step: in Php script you will have to change echo $command_name, to echo result from DB based on $dsn. So echo result from DB.

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH);
echo $row["Command_name"]; //This should show ON/OFF state from DB to AJAX.
```

Comment: Third step:  You have there IF dt.Command_name = ".....  I think there should be IF dt = "on" because AJAX puts into variable DATA output from your PHP script. For example your PHP script will echo ON (state based on $dsn) and AJAX will put this ON into variable DATA. So it is wrong (dt.Command_name). You have to change it.

Comment: It's still giving me error at line 5 `$cmd_Name = $_REQUEST['Command_Name'];`

Comment: I forgot sorry this line in unnecessary. Delete it, you will not read cmd_name from REQUEST but from DB.

Comment: Ok let me have a try on that

Comment: I tried this solution on my server and it works !!! I dont have Idea, maybe check if your input has id="cmn-toggle-7"

Comment: I HAVE AN ANSWER --- " tdata is not defined" YOU will have to ERASE Command_name: tdata, THERE have to stay only Device_serial_number. And you will see Have a nice day